# Split list of strings every nth character

Tags: python

I have a list containing the following:

```
lst = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl']
```

and in addition

```
n=2
```

I want it to look like this (the string will be splitted according to n):

```
['ab', 'bc' ,'ef' ,'gh','ij' , 'kl']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to implement this?

Comment: Or even tried looking for existing answers on SO?

Comment: for i in range(len(lst)):    
        final = [lst[j: j+n] for j in range(0, len(lst[i]), n)]

Comment: Include your attempt in your code instead of posting it as a comment

Comment: edit your question to include the code, and try to fix its formatting using the code markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n=2
lst = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl']
newlist=[x[start:start+2] for x in lst for start in range(0,len(x),n) ]
print(newlist)
```

Output

```
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you join your list to generate a string, you can create a new list using textwrap.wrap:

```
from textwrap import wrap
pairs = wrap("Hello, world!", 2)
```